# .rb file containing multiple classes vs multiple .rb files with a single class in each

Tags: ruby

Commonly I have written programs that have multiple classes in one .rb file. Similarly I have updated programs that use multiple classes, however, each class is in its own .rb file. I can assume that having them in different files would make it easier for a team to all work together or to split work up. But in almost every project I have been assigned I have put all the classes in one file. What is the major advantage or disadvantage of using one file vs multiple and which is better 'ruby' etiquette?

Comment: it depends just on complexity of the classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've already got one great reason: "...having them in different files would make it easier for a team to all work together or to split work up."

Another reason is organization. Suppose I want to know where the User class is defined. If there are a bunch of files and one is named `user.rb`, that's a pretty good clue. If there are a bunch of files and none of them is named `user.rb` I have to start hunting through files, or use a file search utility, and my time is wasted.

Furthermore, if I'm reading a file and it says `require "user"` at the top, I know automatically that this file probably needs something called User. If it says `require "script"` at the top, I have no idea what it's loading, or what's in there that this file needs, so I have to go digging around, and my time is wasted.

A third reason is encapsulation. Keeping code in memory has real performance implications. If there are a dozen different classes in `script.rb` and I do `require "script"`, then I'm loading all of those classes, even if I only want User. Not to mention your tests—and thereby your entire workflow—run a lot faster if they only have to load the things they actually need.

Comment: Awesome, it makes since that requiring a file would make you load all the classes instead of just one making performance decrease significantly depending on how big your file is. Thanks a lot!